# Url Routing working on localhost but Not on server

Tags: iis-7, url-routing, asp.net-3.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I uses asp.net 3.5 for buiding my application,
I use URL routing in it and it works fine in my local host
In my web.config file i do the following setting

```
    <system.web>
    <httpModules>
         <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,                 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
       <add name="RoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
    </system.web>



    <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
    type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,
    System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0,
    Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>


    <handlers>
   <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
    preCondition="integratedMode"
    verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
    type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler,
    System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

But when i deploy the application on my server which has IIS 7 and windows 2008 r2 then routing doesn't work there.I think i have to do some iis setting or to change some web.config code....

so please anyone suggest me some answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about implementing [Page Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28VS.100%29.aspx) from you web-app?

One problem that you might incur, is if your using AJAX (Toolkit or Extensions) you will need to implement:

```
'Ignores any Resource cache references, used heavily in AJAX interactions.
rts.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
```

To keep from getting `Sys is undefined` errors while debugging.